# Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined in Angular2

Tags: angular

In angular2 application getting error on index.html
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qcBY.jpg)

Index.html

```js
import {bootstrap} from '../node_modules/angular2/platform/browser';
import {Login} from './Login';

bootstrap(Login);

Login.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Login</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.8/angular2.dev.js"></script>
     <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/http.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/router.dev.js"></script>

    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.0/backbone.localStorage-min.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                app: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                },
            },
            map: {  // in lieu of index.html script src reference because where using systemjs not commonjs module loader
                'angular2-jwt': 'node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js'
            }
        });
        System.import('app/main').then(null, console.error.bind(console));




    </script>
</head>
<!-- Run the application -->
<body>
    <h1>Angular 2 Form builder </h1>
    <Login>Loading Sample...</Login>

 
</body>
</html>
```

```js
login.ts

///<reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>


import {Component, EventEmitter,Output} from '../node_modules/angular2/core';
import {FORM_PROVIDERS, FormBuilder, Validators} from '../node_modules/angular2/common';
//import {bootstrap} from '../node_modules/angular2/platform/browser';

import {LocationStrategy, RouteParams, RouterLink, HashLocationStrategy, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, AsyncRoute} from '../node_modules/angular2/router';

import {bootstrap} from '../node_modules/angular2/platform/browser';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES} from '../node_modules/angular2/common';
import {Employee} from "./employee";




@Component({
    selector: 'Login',
    templateUrl: '/Login.html',
 // directives: [Login]
})



export class Login  {
  //  emp = new Employee('sanjay', 'psingh@newconinfosystems.com', 999999999, '12121'); // this is our green car instance
  
    
    constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
        alert('hello');
    this.onSubmit = fb.group({
        "firstName": ['', Validators.required],
        "streetAddress": ['', Validators.required],
        "zip": ['', Validators.required], "type": ['home']
    });
    }

 submitted = false; //form not submited : default
  data: string; //this variable contains our data

    //Show data after form submit and set submitted to true
    onSubmit(data) {
        alert('xcxc');
        this.submitted = true;
        this.data = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
        console.log(this.data);
    }
}
```

```html
Login.html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [ngFormModel]="form" #f="ngForm"> 
    <div> 
    <div class="formHeading">First Name</div> 
    <input type="text" id="firstName" ngControl="firstName">
     <div class="errorMessage" *ng-if="f.form.controls.firstName.touched && !f.form.controls.firstName.valid">First Name is required</div> </div> 
    <div>
     <div class="formHeading">Street Address</div>
     <input type="text" id="firstName" ngControl="streetAddress">
     <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="f.form.controls.streetAddress.touched && !f.form.controls.streetAddress.valid">Street Address is required</div> 
     </div>
     <div>
     <div class="formHeading">Zip Code</div> <input type="text" id="zip" ngControl="zip">
     <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="f.form.controls.zip.touched && !f.form.controls.zip.valid">Zip code has to be 5 digits long</div> 
     </div>
     <div>
     <div class="formHeading">Address Type</div> <select id="type" ngControl="type"> <option [value]="'home'">Home Address</option> <option [value]="'billing'">Billing Address</option> </select> 
     </div>
     <button type="submit" [disabled]="!f.form.valid">Save</button>
     <div> <div>The form contains the following values</div> <div> {{payLoad}} </div> </div> 
</form>
```

```js
Package.json
{
  "name": "login",
  "version": "0.5.2",
  "description": "An Angular 2 and Bootstrap easy to start, A-Z startup project",
  "repository": {
    "url": "https://github.com/born2net/ng2Boilerplate"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf node_modules doc dist && npm cache clean",
    "clean-install": "npm run clean && npm install",
    "clean-start": "npm run clean && npm start",
    "lint": "tsconfig-lint",
    "docs": "typedoc --options typedoc.json src/app/app.ts",
    "postinstall": "jspm install && gulp development",
    "start": "node dist/server/main.js --env prod"
  },
  "author": "Sean Levy",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-cli": "0.0.*",
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "angular2-redux-util": "^0.5",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.0.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.2.3",
    "bootbox": "^4.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
    "browser-sync": "^2.11.1",
    "chalk": "^1.1.1",
    "crypto": "0.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "es6-module-loader": "^0.17.8",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.6",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.5.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-comment-swap": "0.0.10",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-git": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-inject": "^1.3.1",
    "gulp-insert": "^0.5.0",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.5.4",
    "gulp-rimraf": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.5.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-tslint": "^4.3.1",
    "gulp-tslint-stylish": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-typedoc": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.10.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.2.4",
    "highcharts": "^4.2.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "immutable": "^3.7.6",
    "install": "^0.4.1",
    "is-equal": "^1.4.2",
    "jquery": "^2.2.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.3",
    "live-server": "^0.9.0",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "moment": "^2.11.2",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.3",
    "ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.1.0",
    "ng2-highcharts": "^0.2.4",
    "npm": "^3.5.3",
    "object-path": "^0.9.2",
    "opn": "^4.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^1.0.3",
    "redux-watch": "^1.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "reselect": "^2.0.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.4.4",
    "rsync": "^0.4.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.5",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "superstatic": "^4.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.7.2",
    "tsc": "^1.20150623.0",
    "tsconfig-lint": "^0.2.0",
    "tslint": "^3.2.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.3.12",
    "typescript": "^1.7.3",
    "typings": "^0.6.8",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.16",
    "zone.js": "^0.5.11"
  },
  "jspm": {
    "dependencies": {
      "angular2": "npm:angular2@^2.0.0-beta.6",
      "angular2-polyfill": "npm:angular2-polyfill@^0.0.2",
      "angular2-redux-util": "npm:angular2-redux-util@^0.5.38",
      "angular2-uuid": "npm:angular2-uuid@^1.0.6",
      "bootbox": "npm:bootbox@^4.4.0",
      "bootstrap": "github:twbs/bootstrap@^3.3.6",
      "born2net/ng2-bs3-modal": "github:born2net/ng2-bs3-modal@^0.1.0",
      "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@^0.1.20",
      "highcharts": "npm:highcharts@^4.2.2",
      "immutable": "npm:immutable@^3.7.6",
      "is-equal": "npm:is-equal@^1.4.2",
      "jquery": "npm:jquery@^2.2.0",
      "lodash": "npm:lodash@4.2.1",
      "moment": "npm:moment@^2.11.2",
      "plugin-typescript": "github:frankwallis/plugin-typescript@2.5.6",
      "redux": "npm:redux@^3.2.1",
      "redux-thunk": "npm:redux-thunk@^1.0.3",
      "reflect-metadata": "npm:reflect-metadata@^0.1.3",
      "reselect": "npm:reselect@^2.0.3",
      "rxjs": "npm:rxjs@5.0.0-beta.0",
      "text": "github:systemjs/plugin-text@^0.0.4",
      "ts": "github:frankwallis/plugin-typescript@^2.6.0",
      "typescript": "npm:typescript@1.8.0",
      "underscore": "npm:underscore@^1.8.3",
      "zone.js": "npm:zone.js@^0.5.14"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "clean-css": "npm:clean-css@^3.4.9",
      "ng2-bootstrap": "npm:ng2-bootstrap@^1.0.3"
    }
  }
}
```

i am getting error on index page of uncaught reference error.
Please suggest me how to resolve it.
Thanking you

Comment: Could you make a try with this file: `https://rawgithub.com/systemjs/systemjs/0.19.6/dist/system.js`?

Comment: sorry thierry ,its not working.

Comment: Okay. Where does this error occur?

Comment: What is the content of `index.html` file? I see some `import` in it...

Comment: See this plunkr for a working sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/Rw4kOzKFbVosaoe7dRL1?p=info